# Codeigniter url routing query string

Tags: codeigniter

i need to routing my website url to seo friendly url,  get out this issue?

please check the screen shot.

http://prntscr.com/ke8uf0

Answer (score 0):

Try this. In **routes.php**:

```
$route['products/(:any)'] = 'products/index/$1';
```

In your controller:

```
public function index($product_name) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

In folder applicaion -> config-> routes.php

```
$route['badrumsutrustning/(:any)'] = 'products/index/$1';
```